# I cannot ping anyone in Windows 7 adhoc network

Tags: windows-7, ping, adhoc

We try to create an adhoc network to in Win7. We create it but I cannot send pind to my peers but they can and get ACKs so do you have any idea this is why? Is it about the security setting s of the computer. I off all the firewall and antivirus programs but still same.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Check your driver may be it is driver issue if every thing is fine then do one thing just off the firewalls though it is not mandatory